# trying to find text with wild card integers inside a string in a special format in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, search

I have a piece of code that opens a file and iterates each line
inside the formated text file there will be a piece of text like this:

name.x00y00.whatever

I searching for the x00y00 to see if exists, and copy what is found into a string. The problem is that the numbers change, it is always two digits following the 'x' and two digits following the 'y'. But there is no way to predict what those numbers are. What is the best way to search the text with wild cards for it's existance and copy it?

I am completely new to regex so if somebody could enlightenment me I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import re
print re.findall(r'\.(x\d{2}y\d{2})\.', "name.x00y00.whatever")
# Prints ['x00y00']
```

I've assumed that `name` and `whatever` can change too, and that the `x00y00` piece is always delimited by dots.

`\.` matches a dot, and `\d{2}` means "two digits".  The parentheses capture the piece of the match that they surround.

I'm using `findall` in case there are multiple matches.

Comment: should we limit the number of digits after 'x' and 'y'? They should be always two as description.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> strs= "name.x00y00.whatever"
>>> match = re.search(r'\.(x\d{2}y\d{2})\.',strs)#returns None if pattern is not found
>>> if match:               
...     print match.group(1)
...     
x00y00
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string will always have `.`, then splitting on that would also work:

```
>>> s = 'name.x12345y34.foo.bar.zoo'
>>> s.split('.')[1]
'x12345y34'
```

However, this assumes the format is fixed - its always the second section. It doesn't guarantee that the result will have numbers though, but it may not be required.